# jsPDF images are corrupted when using large jpegs

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I've been trying to use the latest version of jspdf to create a PDF containing images.  However, the images are corrupted (basically just vertical stripes of grey).

The issues appears to be mainly affect jpegs that are captured from the camera directly.  If you take a picture, crop it a little bit smaller and re-save it then it normally displays OK.

I've got a demo hosted at: https://upbeat-franklin-22e659.netlify.app/ that's written in knockout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a bug in the library. You could try to downgrade to an earlier version of jsPDF.

Possibly also open an issue on their github page or look for the issue and try fix it. Maybe this broke it? (from v2.4.0 release notes)

> #3121: Improve addImage performance.

Comment: I have raised the issue as https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/3318